# Onde está API Aliexpress

Tags: api

Bom, não encontro onde possa estar a API do Aliexpress, para me dar algumas funcionalidades e deixar algumas coisas que faço manualmente, automáticas.

Não que eu ache que seja obrigação da empresa disponibilizar uma API, mas eu acredito que empresas de médio para grande porte disponibilizam para fins de acesso a recursos de forma simplificada, menos manual, mais automático.

Grato!

Comment: http://gw.api.alibaba.com/isv/index.htm

Comment: Vou ter que pedir sua ajuda para traduzir isso! rsrs.. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Segue o link para da documentação da API:

[API Doc](http://portals.aliexpress.com/help/help_center_API.html)

Comment: Show, você indicou uma página que acredito que seja uma documentação da API com uma coletânea muito especifica de implementações, API que OnoSendai indicou é a mais completa, mas não deixa de ser válido sua indicação. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma API para dropshipping em https://console.aliexpress.com/

Garante acesso a busca por produtos e criação de pedidos. É meio complicada de configurar, mas não impossível.